# Remove transparency in VIM when terminal is transparent?

Tags: terminal, colorscheme

I want to keep the terminal background somewhat transparent, but when I open vim

```
vim filename.txt
```

it opens it in terminal (as I want) but the background of the vim is somewhat transparent too. Can I make this background not transparent?

Adding this line:

```
hi Normal guibg=#ffffff guifg=#000000 ctermbg=white ctermfg=black
```

results in this:

[image: terminal]

Comment: What operating system and terminal are you using? This is heavily dependent on those, and may even require switching terminal emulators.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a good question about X11 terminalemulators.